# memory leak between ljmp and setjmp

Tags: c, linux, process, segmentation-fault, signals

I have a problem. I am working on a project where there are expected segmentation faults, I have to catch the segmentation faults and change the default behaviour ( i.e. application crash) using setjmp and ljmp mechanism. By the time the code throws a segmentation fault, there are memory allocations already done. Is there any way I can deallocate the memory allocations done after setjmp is called ? 
Simple words: I want to deallocate the memory allocations between the initial call to setjmp and the one called from ljmp. Here is a small but working code which we can discuss ...

Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static jmp_buf buf;



static void 
addSignalToMask()
{
  sigset_t sigset;
  if ( 0 > sigprocmask(0,NULL,&sigset)){
    fprintf(stderr," error while retreiving procmask \n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if ( -1 == sigaddset(&sigset,SIGSEGV) ){
    /* on error errno is set */
    perror(" SIGSEGV cannot be added to signal set \n ");
    exit(1);
  }

  if ( 0 > sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK,&sigset,NULL)){
    fprintf(stderr," error while retreiving procmask \n");
    exit(1);
  }

  fprintf(stdout, " SIG_SEGV added to signal set \n");

  return;
}

static void 
signalHandler(int arg)
{
  fprintf(stdout ," I am in signal handler \n");
  longjmp(buf,1);             // jumps back to where setjmp was called - making setjmp now return 1
}


static void
throwSegmentation()
{
  int * ptr = 0x0;

  /* a leak of 10x4 = 40 bytes */
  void * leak = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);

  /* now attempting to write on address 0x0 */
  *ptr = 0xdeadbeef;
}

static void
setUpAndThrowSeg()
{
 if ( 0 == setjmp(buf) ) {
    fprintf(stdout," jump set \n");
    throwSegmentation();
 }else {                    
    /* remove blocked SIGSEGV from procmask */
    fprintf(stdout," returned from segmentation\n");
    addSignalToMask();
 }
}

int main() {
  int count = 10;
  if (SIG_ERR == signal(SIGSEGV, signalHandler)){
    fprintf(stderr," signal handler not set up \n");
    exit(1);
  }

  while ( 0 != count --) {
    fprintf(stdout, " throwing again \n");
    setUpAndThrowSeg();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could give us some context. Why do you get expected segmentation faults? I'm curious to see a context where a functioning program generates a segmentation fault.

Comment: I will share the abstract...  Encoding and Decoding procedures of some messages received over network are generated using a code generator. Sometimes such a message arrives whose decoding is not handled properly . In such scenerio segmentation fault occurs. Writing security checks in the code would be lot of code (which will be overwritten once the generator generates the code next time). So....

Comment: Your way of handling decoding faults is not going to work. A pointer that doesn't point into valid memory is not necessarily going to produce a segmentation fault upon dereference; especially when it is pointing just past the boundary of a structure, it's far more likely that it just corrupts data. Please try to think of a different way to handle faulty input. What you are trying to do is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Actually this is related to an issue of double free rather then some random memory pointer. So it always cause a segmentation. whenever there is some random message, few pointers get double freed **IMPORTANT I am also curious to know whether there is a way or not around this situation**

Comment: The solution is to fix your code as to not cause any double frees. If you like, you can post the faulty code so people can help you with that.

Comment: I am afraid I am not at liberty to share the code.

Comment: You could try to use `valgrind` or a similar tool to track down your bugs. I can't really help you here.

Comment: thankyou for your help. I just wanted to know that is there a way to free the allocated memory in the mentioned scenerio and I guess the answer to that is **NO** ... I can do some work now to avoid such segmentation faults

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71796/discussion-between-theadnangondal-and-fuzxxl).

Comment: You **should not** use printf() and friends in a signal handler, it is not signal-safe. (and in this case it may actually worsen your problems)

Comment: Agree. This code was written to show what I want to know. Although I would give a heads up your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a way to do this with stock `malloc`. There is no portable facility that allows you to trace what allocations have been done since a certain point in time.

What you could do is something like this: Create a function that wraps `malloc` and adds each newly allocated memory region into a linked-list. When you need to clear memory leaks, traverse this list and `free` all the chunks you find there. Of course, this only works if you can guarantee that no pointers into the allocated regions remain.

It might be a good idea to rework your control flow so no memory allocations happen during the time where you want to abort control.